# Rewrite not working (match multiple)

Tags: mod-rewrite, ubuntu, url-rewriting

Sorry for the poor title.

I have the following rule that I believed was pretty simple:

```
RewriteRule ^(blog|articles|other)(/?)$ articles/?type=$1
```

Then I hit `www.mysite.com/other`

But the page is getting ?type as being 'articles' ?!

Insert picture of me scratching head here.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule will cause infinite looping. Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog|articles|other)(/?)$ articles/?type=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Since target URI is also `/articles/` and that will match condition pattern again and again until Apache runs out of RewriteLimit and throws 500.

Comment: Wonder then why he/she says is getting type='articles'.

Comment: I just removed 'articles' from the (blog|articles|other) which seemed to have fixed it (?) since articles is actually the target as you mentioned.

Comment: Glad to know your problem got resolved. Please mark the answer as accepted to resolve this Q & A.